# M/M/4 queue distribution and expected wait time

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, queueing-theory

I have M/M/4 queue with an arrival rate of λ= 1.5 per minute and an expected service time of 1/γ= 2 minutes. At arrival four persons are being served and 10 are waiting in line.

Q: What distribution does the time from you arrive to you move up one space in the que have? What is the expected time to move up one space?

So my thinking: This would be the same as the distribution for one customer being served moves out of the system. So it would be exponential distribution? I am unsure of the expected value though. I assume it is either 1/γ= 2 minutes or γ = 0.5 minutes, but I am not quite sure. Help?

Comment: The rate at which one fully-occupied server serves is $0.5$ customers / minute, with the time once occupied until the next service is complete being exponentially distributed.  So the rate at which four fully-occupied servers serve is $2$ customers / minute.  That does not quite answer the distribution question, but you are correct that it is exponentially distributed.  Can you see why?  That then allows you to work out the expected time

Comment: I am just starting out in all of this, so sorry for being pretty lost. Intuitively 2 customers / minute should mean 1 customer/30 seconds and 30 seconds would be the expectation. From what I gather from my teacher's notes on a different problem the answer should be 1/γ= 2 minutes though. To me that is not intuitive and way too long, but I don't understand.

Comment: One server has a rate of $0.5$ customers/minute and an expected service time of $2$ minutes.  Four servers have a collective rate of $2$ customers/minute and an expected time until the next service is completed of $0.5$ minutes